# @ConfigurationProperties aspectj-maven-plugin conflict

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

When I use `@ConfigurationProperties` in aspectj-maven-plugin based maven compile process, I'm getting the following error messages:

> [INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error,
>   warning, fail] [WARNING] Field value processing of
>   @ConfigurationProperty meta-data is not supported     :
>
> [ERROR] Internal compiler error: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Failed to write metadata at
>   org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.writeMetaData(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:367)

Here is my pom settings:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.8</version>
     <configuration>
         <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
         <source>${java.version}</source>
         <target>${java.version}</target>
         <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
         <complianceLevel>${java.version   </complianceLevel>
         <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
         <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
         <verbose>true</verbose>
         <!--<aspectLibraries/>-->
     </configuration>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

What's the solution?

Comment: Looks like [the comment on this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4825#issuecomment-166900774) should help.

Comment: it's the exact same stacktrace so I wonder why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: thanks to  Stéphane Nicoll !!!

Comment: I am guessing you had a second look and that fixed the issue for you. I've created [an issue in the Spring Boot tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4847) to clarify the doc.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4847

> Either solution works.
>   I indeed missed the  `<sources/>` in aspectj-maven-plugin proposed in #4825
>
> or adding `<proc>none</proc>` in maven-compiler-plugin
>
> or adding both of them together.

Comment: With either of the solutions aspects don't get woven anymore. You do get rid of the build error, but it's not much of a fix if your aspects don't get woven.

Comment: Adding `<proc>none</proc>` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the configuration metadata processor attempts reading it's output resource using Filer.getResource and runs into the etc/ajc bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=530665 on Filer.createResource later on.

A workaround may be deleting the META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json prior to compilation via ajc. This however is a poor solution that can not be implemented easily in Maven-based projects.